# Test people standing still or motion in titanium

Tags: android, titanium, accelerometer, accelerator

Now I want to do a app to test people standing still or motion in titanium..I use accelerometer and operated acceleration in 3 axis x,y,z..What I must use formula to test that problem..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to use GPS.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({ backgroundColor: 'white' });

// WARNING: This will only work well outside, where the phone can get a good GPS signal.
var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({ text: 'Traveled 0 ft' });
win.add(label);

// Set up the geolocation code
Ti.Geolocation.accuracy = Ti.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST;
Ti.Geolocation.distanceFilter = 0.1;
Ti.Geolocation.purpose = 'To track how far you have traveled!';
var lastLocation = null, totalFtTraveled = 0;

/**
 * This function is called by the phone every time we have new geolocation data. It writes out where the user currently is.
 * @param e An argument given to us by the phone with information such as accuracy, latitude, and longitude.
 */
function reportPosition(e) {
    if (!e.success || e.error) {
        label.text = 'error: ' + JSON.stringify(e.error);
    }
    else {
        if (lastLocation != null) {
            var lat1 = lastLocation.latitude, lon1 = lastLocation.longitude;
            var lat2 = e.coords.latitude, lon2 = e.coords.longitude;
            var kmTraveled = 3963.0 * Math.acos(
                Math.sin(lat1 / 57.2958) * Math.sin(lat2 / 57.2958)
                    + Math.cos(lat1 / 57.2958) * Math.cos(lat2 / 57.2958)
                    * Math.cos(lon2 / 57.2958 - lon1 / 57.2958)
            );
            var ftTraveled = kmTraveled * 3280.8399;
            totalFtTraveled += ftTraveled;
            label.text = 'Traveled ' + totalFtTraveled + 'ft';
        }
        lastLocation = e.coords;
    }
}

// This will get the location right now, and will get the phone ready to listen for the user's current location.
Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(reportPosition);
// And this fires whenever the "distance filter" is surpassed -- with a filter of 1, this happens every 1 meter or so.
Ti.Geolocation.addEventListener('location', reportPosition);

var reset = Ti.UI.createButton({ title: 'Reset', bottom: 10, height: 50, width: 200 });
reset.addEventListener('click', function() {
    totalFtTraveled = 0;
    label.text = 'Traveled 0ft';
});
win.add(reset);

win.open();
```

Comment: Thank but i must use accelerometer here :)

Answer (score 1):

First, get scalar acceleration independent of movement direction by formula `accel = sqrt(accel_x^2 + accel_y^2 + accel_z^2)` where `^2` means *power of 2* and `sqrt` means a square root. After that, apply some low-pass filter to get rid of random noise. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Algorithmic_implementation) is a good algorithm and using `alpha=0.8` for it would be a good approach. Now, you can just see whether filtered acceleration is greater than some threshold value (sensitivity depends on this threshold). Good luck!

Comment: Do you tell me extractly about testing : people is standing still or moving..I read document at that link but I don't rather understand..Thank

Comment: That link leads to the low-pass filter algorithm from Wikipedia, exactly to digital implementation (because it's not obvious if you never had deal with digital filtering). It's needed because accelerometers has their own noise. The whole algorithm of testing whether a person stays still or is moving I explained in my answer above. I'd write you a code but I never used Titanium, sorry. I write in Java for Android.

Comment: Ok..If you can write code by Java,I can covert to Titanium :D..I only need a formula or an expression to determine people standing still or moving :)..Thank